# BSOD ntoskrnl.exe - memtest+HD tune no error

Tags: windows, bsod, smart, memtest, ntoskrnl.exe

I got 4 BSOD on early June. I ran several tests (memtest standard, SSD and HDD test) and I didn't find any problem. I then cleanly reinstalled Windows and have been running for a month without any blue screen.
However, a new BSOD just appeard. I was only surfing on the internet and here the BSOD was triggered by a call attempt on facebook messenger, but it was rather randomly, before

Here is a minidump, I hope it will help. Anyone has an idea ? I do not have the old minidump but as far as I remember, they were all different (BUT always on that ntoskrnl.exe So i would say RAM could be in cause )
HD Tune scans revealed no error on disks.

Memtest :
After 10 hours running Windows integrated extended memtest, the test was not finished. % could not be displayed (was around 25% I believe), and keystrokes were slow...But "no error" was displayed. I cancelled the test.
I then did a "real" memtest86 (~ 3 hours), no error (4 passes, full tests)

minidump archive : https://we.tl/t-std7yGfjLE

Crystaldiskinfo :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
CrystalDiskInfo 8.6.2 (C) 2008-2020 hiyohiyo
                                Crystal Dew World: https://crystalmark.info/
----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    OS : Windows 10  [10.0 Build 19041] (x64)
  Date : 2020/07/09 18:37:28

-- Controller Map ----------------------------------------------------------
 + Contrôleur AHCI SATA standard [ATA]
   - HGST HTS721010A9E630
 + Contrôleur NVM Express standard [SCSI]
   - KINGSTON RBUSNS8154P3256GJ
 - Contrôleur des espaces de stockage Microsoft [SCSI]

-- Disk List ---------------------------------------------------------------
 (1) HGST HTS721010A9E630 : 1000,2 GB [0/0/0, pd1]
 (2) KINGSTON RBUSNS8154P3256GJ : 256,0 GB [1/1/0, sq] - nv

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (1) HGST HTS721010A9E630
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Model : HGST HTS721010A9E630
        Firmware : JB0OA3U0
   Serial Number : JR100XBNHN0YUE
       Disk Size : 1000,2 GB (8,4/137,4/1000,2/1000,2)
     Buffer Size : 32767 KB
     Queue Depth : 32
    # of Sectors : 1953525168
   Rotation Rate : 7200 RPM
       Interface : Serial ATA
   Major Version : ATA8-ACS
   Minor Version : ATA8-ACS version 6
   Transfer Mode : SATA/600 | SATA/600
  Power On Hours : 4762 hours
  Power On Count : 1151 count
     Temperature : 45 C (113 F)
   Health Status : Good
        Features : S.M.A.R.T., APM, 48bit LBA, NCQ
       APM Level : 4080h [ON]
       AAM Level : ----
    Drive Letter : D: E:

-- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
ID Cur Wor Thr RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 100 100 _62 000000000000 Read Error Rate
02 100 100 _40 000000000000 Throughput Performance
03 136 136 _33 001600000002 Spin-Up Time
04 _98 _98 __0 000000000ED4 Start/Stop Count
05 100 100 __5 000000000000 Reallocated Sectors Count
07 100 100 _67 000000000000 Seek Error Rate
08 100 100 _40 000000000000 Seek Time Performance
09 _90 _90 __0 00000000129A Power-On Hours
0A 100 100 _60 000000000000 Spin Retry Count
0C 100 100 __0 00000000047F Power Cycle Count
BF 100 100 __0 000000000000 G-Sense Error Rate
C0 100 100 __0 00000000000A Power-off Retract Count
C1 _93 _93 __0 000000012F4F Load/Unload Cycle Count
C2 133 133 __0 0037000D002D Temperature
C4 100 100 __0 000000000000 Reallocation Event Count
C5 100 100 __0 000000000000 Current Pending Sector Count
C6 100 100 __0 000000000000 Uncorrectable Sector Count
C7 200 200 __0 000000000000 UltraDMA CRC Error Count
DF 100 100 __0 000000000000 Load/Unload Retry Count

-- IDENTIFY_DEVICE ---------------------------------------------------------
        0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
000: 045A 3FFF C837 0010 0000 0000 003F 0000 0000 0000
010: 2020 2020 2020 4A52 3130 3058 424E 484E 3059 5545
020: 0003 FFFF 0004 4A42 304F 4133 5530 4847 5354 2048
030: 5453 3732 3130 3130 4139 4536 3330 2020 2020 2020
040: 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 8010 4000 2F00
050: 4000 0200 0200 0007 3FFF 0010 003F FC10 00FB 0110
060: FFFF 0FFF 0000 0007 0003 0078 0078 0078 0078 0000
070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 001F 970E 0006 005E 0040
080: 01FC 0028 746B 7D69 6163 7469 BC49 6163 017F 0052
090: 0053 4080 FFFE 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
100: 6DB0 7470 0000 0000 0000 0000 6003 74DC 5000 CCA8
110: E6D7 3289 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 401C
120: 401C 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0029 000B
130: 0000 0000 2182 1CF1 FA00 0000 4000 2000 0004 0000
140: 0000 0603 0703 0603 0703 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
150: 0000 0005 304F 4233 0000 6804 0000 5DBD 97B0 8000
160: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0003 0000
170: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
180: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
190: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
200: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 003D 0000 0000 4000
210: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1C20 0000 0000
220: 0000 0000 103F 0021 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
230: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001 03E0 0000 0000 0000 0000
240: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
250: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 A9A5

-- SMART_READ_DATA ---------------------------------------------------------
     +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
000: 10 00 01 0B 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 05
010: 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 07 00 88 88 02
020: 00 00 00 16 00 00 04 12 00 62 62 D4 0E 00 00 00
030: 00 00 05 33 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 0B
040: 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 05 00 64 64 00
050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 12 00 5A 5A 9A 12 00 00 00
060: 00 00 0A 13 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 32
070: 00 64 64 7F 04 00 00 00 00 00 BF 0A 00 64 64 00
080: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 32 00 64 64 0A 00 00 00 00
090: 00 00 C1 12 00 5D 5D 4F 2F 01 00 00 00 00 C2 02
0A0: 00 85 85 2D 00 0D 00 37 00 00 C4 32 00 64 64 00
0B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C5 22 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00
0C0: 00 00 C6 08 00 64 64 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C7 0A
0D0: 00 C8 C8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 DF 0A 00 64 64 00
0E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
100: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
110: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 2D 00 01 5B
170: 03 00 01 00 02 A6 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 DD

-- SMART_READ_THRESHOLD ----------------------------------------------------
     +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
000: 10 00 01 3E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 28
010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 21 00 00 00 00
020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
030: 00 00 05 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 43
040: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 28 00 00 00 00
050: 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
060: 00 00 0A 3C 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0C 00
070: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 BF 00 00 00 00 00
080: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
090: 00 00 C1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C2 00
0A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C4 00 00 00 00 00
0B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 C5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0C0: 00 00 C6 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 C7 00
0D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 DF 00 00 00 00 00
0E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
100: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
110: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
170: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 89

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 (2) KINGSTON RBUSNS8154P3256GJ
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
           Model : KINGSTON RBUSNS8154P3256GJ
        Firmware : E8FK11.C
   Serial Number : 50026B76821C47E6
       Disk Size : 256,0 GB
     Buffer Size : Unknown
    # of Sectors : 
   Rotation Rate : ---- (SSD)
       Interface : NVM Express
   Major Version : NVM Express 1.2
   Minor Version : 
   Transfer Mode : PCIe 3.0 x2 | PCIe 3.0 x2
  Power On Hours : 2604 hours
  Power On Count : 1155 count
      Host Reads : 9142 GB
     Host Writes : 6099 GB
     Temperature : 63 C (145 F)
   Health Status : Good (95 %)
        Features : S.M.A.R.T.
       APM Level : ----
       AAM Level : ----
    Drive Letter : C:

-- S.M.A.R.T. --------------------------------------------------------------
ID RawValues(6) Attribute Name
01 000000000000 Critical Warning
02 00000000014F Composite Temperature
03 000000000064 Available Spare
04 000000000064 Available Spare Threshold
05 000000000005 Percentage Used
06 000001248F78 Data Units Read
07 000000C32FA2 Data Units Written
08 00000ED9F8DC Host Read Commands
09 00000E77FBE7 Host Write Commands
0A 00000000044D Controller Busy Time
0B 000000000483 Power Cycles
0C 000000000A2C Power On Hours
0D 00000000001B Unsafe Shutdowns
0E 000000000000 Media and Data Integrity Errors
0F 000000000020 Number of Error Information Log Entries

-- IDENTIFY_DEVICE ---------------------------------------------------------
        0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
000: 2646 2646 3035 3230 4236 3637 3238 4331 3734 3645
010: 2020 2020 494B 474E 5453 4E4F 5220 5542 4E53 3853
020: 3531 5034 3233 3635 4A47 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020
030: 2020 2020 3845 4B46 3131 432E 0001 B726 0900 0000
040: 0200 0001 4F80 0012 E360 0016 0000 0000 0000 0000
050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
060: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
080: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
090: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
100: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
110: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
120: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0007 0300
130: 0402 040F 0101 0162 0166 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
140: 6000 9E65 003B 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
150: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
160: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
170: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
180: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
190: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
200: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
210: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
220: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
230: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
240: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
250: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000

-- SMART_NVME --------------------------------------------------------------
     +0 +1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 +7 +8 +9 +A +B +C +D +E +F
000: 00 50 01 64 64 05 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
010: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
020: 78 8F 24 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
030: A3 2F C3 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
040: DC F8 D9 0E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
050: 1D FC 77 0E 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
060: 4D 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
070: 83 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
080: 2C 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
090: 1B 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0B0: 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 50 01 00 00 00 00
0D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
0F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
100: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
110: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
120: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
130: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
140: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
150: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
160: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
170: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
180: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
190: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1A0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1B0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1C0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1D0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1E0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
1F0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Here is what bluescreenviewer shows

[BSOD log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dlobj.png)

Or here is what Whocrashed shows :

```
On Thu 09/07/2020 17:07:07 your computer crashed or a problem was reported
crash dump file: C:\Windows\Minidump\070920-12312-01.dmp
This was probably caused by the following module: ntoskrnl.exe (nt+0x3DDA20) 
Bugcheck code: 0x1A (0x41792, 0xFFFFFE3FFC5DF910, 0x1008100000, 0x0)
Error: MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
file path: C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe
product: Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
company: Microsoft Corporation
description: NT Kernel & System
Bug check description: This indicates that a severe memory management error occurred. A corrupted PTE has been detected. 
This might be a case of memory corruption. This may be because of a hardware issue such as faulty RAM, overheating (thermal issue) or because of a buggy driver. This problem might also be caused because of overheating (thermal issue). 
The crash took place in the Windows kernel. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver that cannot be identified at this time. 



On Thu 09/07/2020 17:07:07 your computer crashed or a problem was reported
crash dump file: C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP
This was probably caused by the following module: ntkrnlmp.exe (nt!memset+0x6364E) 
Bugcheck code: 0x1A (0x41792, 0xFFFFFE3FFC5DF910, 0x1008100000, 0x0)
Error: MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
Bug check description: This indicates that a severe memory management error occurred. A corrupted PTE has been detected. 
This might be a case of memory corruption. This may be because of a hardware issue such as faulty RAM, overheating (thermal issue) or because of a buggy driver. This problem might also be caused because of overheating (thermal issue). 
The crash took place in the Windows kernel. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver that cannot be identified at this time.
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm not downloading your minidump. What does https://www.resplendence.com/whocrashed say about your minidump?

Comment: I've just added a screenshot of bluescreenviewer info.
Do you want me to use whocrashed instead?

Comment: The error is with memory management in the kernel, but is perhaps very intermittent. I suggest running memtest86 overnight and for as long as possible.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try a longer memtest this saturday. I already 4 passes (~3 hours) and no error

Comment: Well, memtest is limited to 4 passes in the free edition

Comment: after 15 windows memtest standard passes, no error